# UIDatePicker drawing glitch in iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uidatepicker

When adding a `UIDatePicker` to my view hierarchy I'm seeing this strange glitch where the selected date components have a non-transparent background:

[image: UIDatePicker glitch]

The date picker is above a `UIImageView` which contains an image with transparency, so the underlying view is visible (which is what I want). When I scroll the wheels a little bit, the glitch goes away eventually.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: The problem here is that you don't want to see the red and blue image right?

Comment: I see the same sort of behavior with a UIInputView as an inputAccessoryView -- the background color is significantly transparent till I fiddle with the background (a table) a little bit and then it changes to match the background of the keyboard.  I'm interested to hear a good answer to this question.  I solved my problem by setting the background color of the UIInputView to something close to the keyboard background so although it probably isn't exactly right the visual glitch is too small to notice.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not clearly describe the difference between the glitch and what I want to achieve :) I edited the question accordingly.